# Properties of convex function with Lipshitz continuous gradient (Prof. Nesterov's textbook)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

I am reading the Prof. Nesterov's textbook:
`Introductory lectures on convex optimization - a basic course`  p.57

I have problem in the following:

[image]
[image]

> My question is how to get the green box?
>
> I have trouble to get the green box from (2.1.6); particularly, how to put $L$ to denominator.

Note: To my question, you can assume (2.1.6) is known and just stat from "Further, let us fix $x_0\in R^n$".

Comment: If you don't mind would you please explain after deriving the green box how did you get  the result. using the given hint I tried to substitue $\phi ^{\prime}(y) = f^{\prime}(y)  -  f^{\prime}(x_0)$ and $\phi(y) = f(y)- \langle f^{\prime}(x_0),y\rangle $ to derive it but I couldn't. I would appreciate any insights. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Crimson 1. plug in the definition for $\phi(y)$ in the green box.  2. let $y-x=\frac{1}{L}\phi'(y)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you v. much for your answer. Do you mean $y-x_0 = \frac{1}{L} \phi^{\prime}(y)$  or $y-x= \frac{1}{L} \phi^{\prime}(y)$? ( I just plugged in as you wrote and I thought may be you meant $x_0$. I am not sure about it).  $y-x = \frac{1}{L} \phi^{\prime}(y)$  is a new assumption or it is something I should conclude? Sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: @Crimson I think that is for $x$ not $x_0$ (but I think this is a small problem to check). To the second question, I do not think this is a new assumption; this is just the definition of differentiation. (Not quite sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a direct calculation. First inequality is followed from definition of $y^\ast$ For the second we use (2.1.6) :

$$ \phi \bigg(y- \frac{\phi'}{L}\bigg) -\phi (y) -\bigg(\phi'(y), - \frac{\phi'}{L}\bigg) \leq \frac{L}{2}\| - \frac{\phi'}{L}\|^2 $$